# creating and accessing an object in xhtml (prime faces)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, javabeans

how do i access the created object on a jsf page? I don't want to make the object as a property of this bean. below is the sample code that I am trying to use

```
import org.Server;

@ManagedBean
public class IntroBean {
private int id;
private String name;  


public String doSend() {
    Server server = new Server();
    server.setId(id);
    server.setName(name);
    return("send-page");
}
```

now I want to access the `server` object on `send-page.xhtml`.
here is the code for xhtml page

```
<h2>Id : #{server.id}</h2>
<h2>Name : #{server.name}</h2>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have not defined the name of bean neither its scope. Question is really vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved by putting the desired object into one of the implicit EL objects, e.g `sessionScope` :

```
private Map<String,Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
...
public String doSend(){
    Server server = new Server();
    server.setId(id);
    server.setName(name);    
    sessionMap.put("serverObject", server);
    return("send-page");
}
```

Then, get it in the view by:

```
<h2>Id : #{sessionScope['serverObject'].id}</h2>
<h2>Name : #{sessionScope['serverObject'].name}</h2>
```

As per the new requirement, it might be done by using the implicit EL object within the input component :

```
Change the name of the server : 
<h:inputText value="#{sessionScope['serverObject'].name}">
```

In the end, retrieve the desired object in the backing bean by:

```
public String doSave(){    
    Server server2 = (Server)sessionMap.get("serverObject");
    ...
}
```

Comment: This helped but isn't there some other way so that the changes done on this view are reflected into the same object.

Answer (score 0):

JSF needs proper getter/setter methods in the backing bean, I don't see those for `server` in your code. Check out http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/primefaces-hello-world-example/

Comment: if I create geter setter for server I need to make server a property of `IntroBean` but `Server` is a seperate bean which has its own setter/getters. read the question properly.